# Unable to read the webcam stream : VideoCapture

Tags: python, video-capture

I'm working on Windows10 and coding in Python.
I'm trying to read live stream from webcam.

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

(rval, im) = webcam.read()
```

After I checked value of 'im'; it is 'None'.
Am I missing anything? Please help.

Comment: Please show a working piece of code you wrote yet and sample data about your trial to solve this problem. So we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

webcam = cv2.VideoCpature(0) # If 0 doesn't work try swapping it with 1

while True:
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

try running that ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sReEzHtBBRY&list=PL6Yc5OUgcoTmTGACTa__vnifNA744Cz-q&index=2))